# Synapse Analytics save a query result in a blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

So, I have some parquet files stored in azure devops containers inside a blob storaged. I used data factory pipeline with the "copy data" connector to extract the data from a on premise Oracle database.

I'm using Synapse Analytics to do a sql query that uses some of the parquet files store in the blob container and I want to save the results of the query in another blob. Which Synapse connector can I use the make this happen? To do the query I'm using the "develop" menu inside Synapse Analytics.

Comment: Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but the only way I know to persist serverless SQL query results is with External Table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas

Comment: Thank you a lot @JoelCochran i think that will do the job. If you want to put that as an answer i will mark the green check for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist the results of a serverless SQL query, use [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT (CETAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas). This will create a physical copy of the result data in your storage account as a collection of files in a folder, so you cannot specify how many files nor the naming scheme of the files.