# How to save SQL query results from Azure Synapse to cloud storage files

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I want to run an SQL query in Azure Synapse and store the results in some format (like compressed CSV) in Azure Blob or Azure Data Lake.  Ideally the results will be a split into a set of blobs of adjustable size (like 32MB each) so we can download and consume them in parallel.

We have already figured out the opposite -- bulk loading from cloud storage is fairly well documented.

In Snowflake, we do this by creating an internal stage, using `COPY INTO @stage FROM (query)` and then downloading the stage files using the `GET` command.  Does Synapse supported something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the **CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT (CETAS)** statement in both dedicated and serverless SQL pools to achieve the following:

- Create an external table
- Export the results of a **Transact-SQL SELECT** statement in parallel to Hadoop, Azure Storage Blob, or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

You can create an external table and then export the results of a Transact-SQL SELECT statement in parallel.

Know more about the [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT (CETAS) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-as-select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=powershell)

To create an external table in Azure Synapse serverless, follow the steps below:

**Step 1:** Right-click on the folder/file you want to create an external table for:

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:**

[image]

**Results:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.emp_ext_tbl01 (
[emp_id] Int,
[emp_name] nvarchar(4000),
[emp_role] nvarchar(4000),
[emp_salary] int
)
WITH (
LOCATION = 'employeetbl.csv',
DATA_SOURCE = [folder02_stgforsynp_dfs_core_windows_net],
FILE_FORMAT = [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat]
)
GO
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.emp_ext_tbl01
```

[image]

***Note: As mentioned, if you want to create a staging folder in a storage account, you can use **COPY ACTIVITY** in Synapse, which directly supports the creation of an internal stage.***

**Reference:** [Synapse Analytics save a query result in a blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965066/synapse-analytics-save-a-query-result-in-a-blob-storage)

Comment: While I appreciate this thought-out answer, I'm having a hard time translating from the general to the specific.  Is there any way to avoid CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE?  With COPY INTO I can put the storage path, credentials, format, everything into a single command and (seemingly) avoid the "polybase" layer.